# What is the difference between this.setMethod(parameter) and setMethod(parameter) in a constructor? [Java]

Tags: java, oop, constructor

I have been trying to learn about classes and objects for the last few days and I realized that using "this.set" and "set" inside a constructor made no apparent difference. To clarify

```
public Movie(String title,String director, String rating) {
        setTitle(title); 
        setDirector(director);
        setRating(rating);
```

and

```
public Movie(String title,String director, String rating) {
        this.setTitle(title); 
        this.setDirector(director);
        this.setRating(rating);
```

made no difference while running.

What is the difference, if there is any and which one is better practice?

I was expecting there to be some kind of error, but it worked completely the same. In addition, my instructor does  **not** use "this." while putting a setter inside a constructor in his examples.

Thanks.

Comment: In almost all cases these are the same. I'm trying to think of a situation where not using `this.` would produce different results....

Comment: [This](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/113430/349474) stack exchange discussion has some interesting answers for your 'which one is better practice' question.

Comment: @Matt Hmm, I'm a beginner at programming so I can't fully comprehend what the question or the answers fully mean, but when I can I'll definitely read it. Bookmarked.

Comment: It seems like the 'best practice' is highly up for debate, so you're likely free to use whatever makes most sense to you without any consequences :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to use `this` when calling the setter methods in your example (and it's not standard practice to do so). However, it is necessary to use `this` if you want to set a field with the same name as a variable in the constructor. For example:

```
public class Movie {
    private final String title;

    public Movie(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

If you don't specify `this.title`, it will think you are trying to assign the `title` variable to itself.

The keyword `this` is also needed to distinguish different implementations of methods when your class has extended another class (e.g. you can call `this.method()` or `super.method()`.)

Answer (score 1):

With `this.*` you are calling the method located at "this" instance. When inheriting from a class having implemented the same method(s), you also have the opportunity to call super.setTitle().

Or with an example:

```java
class Foo
{
    public int baz()
    {
        return -1;
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    private Bar()
    {
        super.baz(); // returns -1
        this.baz(); // returns 1
    }

    public int baz()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I haven't learnt "super" yet but when I do I'll make sure I come back to this answer.

Comment: @tohli when you create an instance of an class, which inherits from another class, you are using super already, but the compiler generate it for you. In a constructor for example of the class Bar above, there is an implicit call to `super()` which calls the constructor of `Foo` (which is in this case also the implicit default no-args constructor). And because all classes derive from `Object` every class implicitly calls `super`.